# NetBeans Include External JAR in Export to Zip

Tags: netbeans, gson

I have a NetBeans project that uses the GSON library.  I've tried including the GSON.jar file without requiring future users to separately download it. However it doesn't seem to work.  The project looks for the file from the relative path of my computer so the file isn't found on another user's computer.  Is there a way to include GSON.jar and "Export to Zip" and keep the reference in the project itself?  I'm lost!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a Project to ZIP zips up the project folder only, and not anything outside of the folder, including dependencies. If you include the `GSON.jar` file in the project folder, then the `JAR` file will be included in the `.ZIP` file. It's a good practice anyway since NetBeans will use a relative classpath and thus if you move the project itself NetBeans won't give you an error message when loading the project.